# Why are form-feed and vertical tab treated differently inside of single-line comments?

Tags: c++, character, comments, control-characters

In ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (C++17) is stated under Section 5.7, "Comments":

> 5.7  Comments[lex.comment]
>
> 1 The characters `/*` start a comment, which terminates with the characters `*/`. These comments do not nest. The characters `//` start a comment, which terminates immediately before the next new-line character. **If there is a form-feed or a vertical-tab character in such a comment, only white-space characters shall appear between it and the new-line that terminates the comment; no diagnostic is required.** [Note: The comment characters `//` , `/*` , and `*/` have no special meaning within a `//` comment and are treated just like other characters. Similarly, the comment characters `//` and `/*` have no special meaning within a `/*` comment.— end note]

Why are form-feed and vertical tab characters treated differently inside of a single-line comment?

What is the reason for that?

And why doesn´t  that also apply to multi-line comments `*/` `/*`?

Comment: Is the C17 on the first line intended to be C++17?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, sorry. That was a typo. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: My guess would be that this accomodates environments where FF/VT is implicitly treated as a newline (not difficult to imagine such), and this is the simplest way to avoid having any non-whitespace content that follows FF/VT to be treated as code, in such environments.